# Backup Server Solution in production environment

Tags: windows, backup

I was looking at setting up a backup server running on a virtualbox with Windows Server 2008r2 as the host (I have no say here). I was thinking about using FreeNAS with ZFS, however, I am finding out that some have had problems with this due to S.M.A.R.T. and windows paging when running FreeNAS on a virtual Machine.

This Backup Server will be responsible for backing up our whole infrastructure in increments of a week (already have an on site full backup solution).

Does Windows have any backup server-client applications that would both be VM friendly and have the performance to backup TeraBytes of data?

hardware specs are not a problem here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: VirtualBox? Seriously?! That part is probably a very bad idea.

Comment: Why would you use Virtualbox when you have Hyper-V built in to the OS?

Comment: trust me I love Hyper-V but we have already set up another server with 5 virtual machines with virtual box (ADDC, email etc.). With that said having a second Server running something different would just anger my seniors. Apparently I am in charge of this Server so I may just go ahead and bite the bullet and go over their heads but don't know if that would be a smart idea if I am trying to move ahead.

Comment: Cant tell if... trolling or serious...

Comment: What does Hyper-V have over virtualbox for Server applications in production?

Comment: A lot. More than can be explained in a comment. Virtualbox is for desktop virtualization, not for production server virtualization.

Comment: From my experience hyper-v does that hypervisor crashing thing a lot less than virtualbox too.  That alone is reason enough.

Comment: Good to know, did a little bit of searching an noticed a lot of reasons to use Hyper-V.

Still need to know how am I going to backup from each workstation to the backup server running windows backup.

Comment: wait, backing up workstations? That's an entire different issue completely. This is more of a "What are you really trying to accomplish" question at this point.

Answer (score 2):

> Does Windows have any backup server-client applications that would both be VM friendly and have the performance to backup TeraBytes of data?

The only built-in option that you have is configuring Windows Server Backup on each server and having the guest simply be file storage for the backups. If you want a Microsoft-provided backup solution that is more "enterprise friendly" with centralized reporting, backup policies, etc you're going to need to purchase System Center Data Protection Manager.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. I will probably go with this.